# Using views for NumPy broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Suppose I have a 2D np.array `X`, and I need to use `X[:, None, :]` in some intermediate computations; for instance 
`np.sum(X[:, None, :] == Y[None, :, :], axis=2)` where `Y` is also a 2D np.array.

Does this operation explicitly copies the memory for `X` and `Y` to create `X[:, None, :]` and `Y[:, None, :]`? If so, is there a way to avoid this copying by using views in NumPy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X[:, None, :]` and `Y[None, :, :]` are already views. Both operations are NumPy [basic slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), which always generates a view.

`X[:, None, :] == Y[None, :, :]` is going to be a much bigger memory problem, as it creates a very large boolean array. You can avoid this by rewriting your computation in terms of [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) in `'hamming'` mode:

```
In [10]: x
Out[10]: 
array([[3, 0, 2, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 1, 1, 1]])
In [11]: y
Out[11]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 1, 1, 2, 1]])
In [12]: numpy.sum(x[:, None, :] == y[None, :, :], axis=2)
Out[12]: 
array([[3, 1, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 3]])
In [13]: 5 - 5*cdist(x, y, 'hamming') # 5 for the row length of x and y
Out[13]: 
array([[ 3.,  1.,  3.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  1.,  3.]])
```

There's no option to compute non-normalized hamming distances in `scipy.spatial.distance`, so we have to undo the normalization.

Comment: Ah, this is very helpful. Thanks! However, I'm not sure how to use `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` to compute the Hamming distance between each row of `X` and each row of `Y`, not the distances between the rows of `X` itself?

Comment: Of course, I could append `Y` to `X` and then call `pdist`, but this would be quite wasteful since I only need 1/4 of the results.

Comment: @Hilbert: Whoops, I meant cdist. I forgot which one was the two-matrix function. (Even if cdist weren't a thing, pdist would likely still be more efficient than generating the giant boolean array, though.)

Comment: Ah, great. Thank you!